# Problemas com instalação do Netbeans e Javafx no ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Estou tentando continuar um projeto (javafx) após ter formatado minha máquina com o linux Ubuntu 16.04. Instalei o default-jdk pelo terminal antes de instalar o  netbeans 8.2 completo baixado direto do site da Oracle e quando tento abrir o projeto da um erro na leitura e ele aparece na aba "Projetos" com "(interrompido)" na frente. Quando tento iniciar um novo projeto javafx aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Tentando criar um novo projeto javafx]

Tentei instalar o openjfx pelo terminal sem sucesso. Então tentei o netbeans 8.1 pelo terminal. Sem sucesso novamente, porém, nele o projeto abre mas não roda e obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
ant -f /home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: /home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
Deleting directory /home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/dist/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/dist/lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Internal error. Missing resources [/resources/web-files/javafx-loading-100x100.gif]
JNLP failed : Error: -includedt requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution
com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerException: Error: -includedt requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.jnlp.JNLPBundler.execute(JNLPBundler.java:493)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:318)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$11$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:405)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:109)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:53)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(Unknown Source)
/home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1487: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3134: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cezar/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/TCC/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:2096: Error: Bundler "WebStart JNLP Bundler" (jnlp) failed to produce a bundle.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Além disso, no netbeans 8.1 não encontro nem a opção de criar um projeto javafx na janela de novo projeto.

Comment: Tente instalar o javafx antes: `sudo apt-get install openjfx`.

Comment: Eu já tive problemas com o OpenJDK usando o linux, sugiro que você uso o java 8 da Oracle mesmo. Quanto aos módulos ele está procurando uma versão antiga do JavaFX (2).